# Numerical analysis: Three point method

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Hoping for some advice as to how to tackle this question from Numerical analysis. I assume some form of the three point formula is used, however the mid/end point formula seem to fail since there is no common $h$ between the given $x_i$ values.

Given Points $x_1,x_2,x_3$, for $y\in\mathbb{R}$, let
$$L_i(y)= \prod\limits^{3}_{k=1;k\neq i}\frac{y-x_k}{x_i -x_k}.$$
Then if $|y-x_i| = O(h)$ for $i = 1,2,3$, then
$$f(y) = \sum\limits^{2}_{i=0}L_i(y)f(x_i) + O(h^2).$$
Given that 
$$L_1'(y) = \frac{2y-x_2-x_3}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)},$$
$$L_2'(y) = \frac{2y-x_1-x_3}{(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)},$$ and
$$L_3'(y) = \frac{2y-x_1-x_2}{(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)}.$$
Estimate $f'(0.2)$ given $f(0) = 1.2, f(0.3) = 1.6$ and $f(0.5) = 2.0$.

Comment: Did you have problems in inserting the constants in the formula $f'(0.2)\approx\sum f(x_i)L_i'(0.2)$? Or was there an error estimate also required?

Comment: My notes suggest that the points I can use in the (differentiated) formula are $x_i$, $i=1,2,3.$ It only asks for an estimate and does not ask for an estimate on the error. The main reason I am confused is because $x=0.2$ is not one of the three points that I am given.

Comment: The quadratic interpolation polynomial provides an estimate for the function on $[0, 0.5]$. Taking values and derivatives of the polynomial is the best guess for the values of the function.